# Can't debug init.el

Tags: emacs, auctex

I get the following error when I open emacs in Mac OSX:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading 
`/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/init.el':
Symbol's value as variable is void: Synctex

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I then start emacs using `--debug-init` and get the following:

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Unknown keyword :risky")
signal(error ("Unknown keyword :risky"))
error("Unknown keyword %s" :risky)
custom-handle-keyword(package-load-list :risky t custom-variable)
custom-declare-variable(package-load-list (quote (all)) "List of packages for `package-initialize' to load.\nEach eleme$
(defcustom package-load-list (quote (all)) "List of packages for `package-initialize' to load.\nEach element in this li$
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<3>> nil "/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/package.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 9131
load-with-code-conversion("/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/package.el" "/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/package.el" nil t)
require(package)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 17$
load-with-code-conversion("/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" "/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil$
load("/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil t)
load-file("/Users/my-user-name/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el")
```

Can anybody help me sort through this? This is my first time trying to debug/edit init.el.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question does not seem to fit in with the [scope of TeX-sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq): could you explain the link to TeX?

Comment: I believe you are right. The only link is that I am using emacs for typesetting in LaTeX, nothing else. If necessary please delete my post.

Comment: @jvcasill: Removing isn't necessary but I think guys of the site stackoverflow are more competent.

Comment: @jvcaskill Here or on stackoverflow a MWE should include your `init.el` file as well as the error messages.

Comment: The most likely problem is a forgotten quote, i.e. somewhere in your `init.el` you've written `Synctex` when you actually should have written `'Synctex`. Another possibility would be that you used a wrong case (ELisp is case sensitive!), that is you've written `Synctex` when you should have written `synctex` or maybe `SyncTeX`). Anyway, the location of the error should be easily found by looking for the string `Synctex` in your `init.el`.

Comment: This was the solution. There was a section that said 'Synctex with skim' that had to be commented out. Everything is working properly now.